# Can Seagate Expansion external HDD be connected to desktop SATA bus?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata

Please help, help is needed.

I am terribly sorry if my wording is unprofessional, I am a Chinese and I don't even know how to express them in Chinese!

Long story short, recently I have run some tests on my Seagate Expansion 2TB (1863 GiB ish) external HDD, and the results show some random bad sectors with cylinder numbers changing each time, I have preliminarily excluded the possiblity of physical bad sectors, and when I open Seatools, it displays only two devices: the internal HDD and external HDD, while it normally will display the external hard disk enclosure as a third device.

I think the USB chip is faulty, so I opened the case of my external HDD, and opened my computer's case, and found out I am unable to connect the HDD to the computer...

So this is my external HDD itself:

[image]

As you can see, the socket of my HDD has two "plates" covered with metal bars extruding from the "main disk", the socket has two parts, one is much larger than the other, I had found a spare SATA bus in my computer, the port is roughly the same size as the big "plate", but I can't quite plug the port into the socket, the shape of the thing holds the HDD in place on the port doesn't match the corresponding part in the socket, and the numbers of metal bars don't match, and I can't found a piece that matches the other part...

So do I have to buy an external HDD enclosure or I can plug the HDD into my computer?

The front cover of my HDD:

[image]

Comment: The connectors on your drive certainly superficially look like normal 7 pin (data) + 15 pin (power) SATA connectors. The Ground (long pins) and Signal/power (short pins) pins do not seem to match with normal SATA for the power connector however. Does the drive have any type/identification?

Comment: @StarCat Which pins don't match? To me they look like on photos available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Cables,_connectors,_and_ports).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I think you’re right. Somehow I compared it to an image of a SATA connector that was different. So scrap my comment. It looks like a perfectly normal SATA connector.

Comment: I had just found out in my computer, there are 2 SATA powerlines extending from power box, 2 SATA sockets on motherboard, but only 1 SATA data bus connected to the internal HDD...It seems the computer assembly people had stole a SATA bus...I still need to spend money, but now I just have to buy a SATA data bus, which is far cheaper than external HDD cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a standard SATA connector. It should work with any computer.

The smaller, 7-pin part is a SATA connector. It connects to the motherboard using a SATA cable.

The larger, 15-pin one is SATA power. Your power supply should have a plug that matches it.

Make sure you're not plugging cables in upside down. The angled protrusions on HDD side should fit into matching holes in respective cables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in fact I have only found a SATA plug that extrudes from the power supply box, so now it's clear it's the power line, so far I haven't found a SATA data cable...